# Linkedin API oAuth 2.0 REST Query parameters

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm running into a problem with adding a query to the callback URL. I'm getting an invalid URI scheme error attempting to authorize the following string:

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=75df1ocpxohk88&scope=rw_groups%20w_messages%20r_basicprofile%20r_contactinfo%20r_network&state=7a6c697d357e4921aeb1ba3793d7af5a&redirect_uri=http://marktest.clubexpress.com/basic_modules/club_admin/website/auth_callback.aspx?type=linkedin

I've read some conflicting information in forum posts here. Some say that it's possible to add query strings to callbacks, and others say that it results in error.

If I remove ?type=linkedin, I can authorize just fine and receive the token. It would make my life so much easier if I could use a query string on the callback url, as I need to do some additional processing in the callback.

**In short, can I append a query string to the end of the callback url?**

For fun, I tried encoding the callback url in the request (obviously this is a no-no according to their documentation):
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=75df1ocpxohk88&scope=rw_groups%20w_messages%20r_basicprofile%20r_contactinfo%20r_network&state=5cabef71d89149d48df523558bd12121&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fmarktest.clubexpress.com%2fbasic_modules%2fclub_admin%2fwebsite%2fauth_callback.aspx%3ftype%3dlinkedin

This also resulted in an error but was worth a shot.

The documetation here: https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/oauth-20-redirect-url-faq-invalid-redirecturi-error indicates that you CAN use query parameters. And in the first request, it appears that I'm doing it correctly. Post #25 on this page - https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/error-while-getting-access-token indicates that you have to remove the query parameters to make it work

**Anyone have experience with successfully passing additional query paramaters in the callback url for the linkedin API using oAuth2.0? If so, what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't wait around for the Linkedin rep's to respond. After *much* experimentation, I can only surmise that the use of additional query parameters in the callback is not allowed (thanks for making my application more complicated).  As it's been suggested in post #25 from the question, I've tucked away the things I need in the "state=" parameter of the request so that it's returned to my callback.

In my situation, I'm processing multiple API's from my callback and requests from multiple users, so I need to know the type and user number. As a solution, I'm attaching a random string to a prefix, so that I can extract the query parameter in my callback and process it. Each state= will therefore be unique as well as giving me a unique key to cache/get object from cache..
so state="Linkedin-5hnx5322d3-543"

so, on my callback page (for you c# folks)

```
_stateString=Request["state"];
_receivedUserId = _stateString.Split('-')[2];
_receivedCacheKeyPrefix = _stateString.Split('-')[0];

if(_receivedCacheKeyPrefix == "Linkedin") {
     getUserDomain(_receivedUserId);
     oLinkedIn.AccessTOkenGet(Request["code"],_userDomain);
     if (oLinkedin.Token.Length > 0) {
     _linkedinToken = oLinkedin.Token;
     //now cache token using the entire _statestring and user id (removed for brevity)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! using the state parameter a put all the needed data there is a good artifice

Answer (score 1):

You not allowed to do that. 
Refer to the doc: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

> **Please note that:**
>
> We strongly recommend using HTTPS whenever possible
>       URLs must be absolute (e.g. "https://example.com/auth/callback", not "/auth/callback")
>       URL arguments are ignored (i.e. https://example.com/?id=1 is the same as https://example.com/)
>       URLs cannot include #'s (i.e. "https://example.com/auth/callback#linkedin" is invalid)